# Get Dropbox version

Tags: elementary-os, dropbox

I'm running [elementary OS](https://elementary.io) which has a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1357938) where the Dropbox icon won't show up in the panel.

Dropbox runs just fine, except that without an icon I can't figure out how to check which version I have installed.

I tried using the command line but there doesn't seem to be an option available to display the version:

```
Dropbox command-line interface

commands:

Note: use dropbox help <command> to view usage for a specific command.

 status       get current status of the dropboxd
 help         provide help
 puburl       get public url of a file in your dropbox
 stop         stop dropboxd
 running      return whether dropbox is running
 start        start dropboxd
 filestatus   get current sync status of one or more files
 ls           list directory contents with current sync status
 autostart    automatically start dropbox at login
 exclude      ignores/excludes a directory from syncing
 lansync      enables or disables LAN sync
```

How can I tell which version of Dropbox I am running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a `~/.dropbox-dist/VERSION` file with the Dropbox version. Beware that it doesn't have the trailing newline you'd expect, so you'd want to `cat` it like this:

```
$ cat .dropbox-dist/VERSION ; echo
3.4.6
```

... otherwise the 3.4.6 will wind up run in to your shell prompt.